# How can I find the Green's function of this modified Poisson equation?

Tags: differential-equations, greens-functions

I am looking for the Green's function necessary to solve the following PDE:
$$
\nabla^2\Phi-\epsilon M\Phi=M,
$$
where $\Phi,M$ are scalar fields in 3D, $\nabla^2$ is the 3D Laplace operator and $\epsilon>0$ is a positive parameter which, if necessary, can be taken to be small. Boundary conditions can be specified to be that $\nabla\Phi$ vanishes at infinity.

What confuses me is that the source is coupled to the field itself, which makes it not clear at all on how I should go about finding a Green's function.

Many thanks.

EDIT: $\Phi$ and $M$ could be taken to be spherically symmetric if necessary

Comment: Try to have a look at Helmholtz equation

Comment: @basics The problem is that Helmholtz equation has M constant, but here it is a spatially dependent field.

Comment: I doubt that it is possible to find a non-singular Green's function for such a equation. I would try to search for it as follows: let $M(\vec{r}) = \delta(\vec{r} - \vec{r}_0)$. Then, the equation reduces to $\nabla^2 \Phi = (1 + \epsilon\Phi(\vec{r}_0))\delta(\vec{r} - \vec{r}_0)$, which is a Laplace equation. We get $\Phi(\vec{r}) = -(1 + \epsilon\Phi(\vec{r}_0))/(4\pi|\vec{r} -\vec{r}_0|)$, which yields a singular value of $\Phi(\vec{r}_0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to view Green's functions as inverse operators. In your case, you want $\Phi$, so the operator you wish to invert is the RHS:
$$
\Delta-\epsilon M
$$
so the Green's function you are looking for is:
$$
(\Delta_x-\epsilon M(x))G(x,y)=\delta(x-y)
$$
Note that since $M$ breaks the translation invariance, $G$ takes two spatial arguments, and does not depend only on the difference. $\Phi$ can therefore be expressed as:
$$
\Phi(x) = \int d^Dy G(x,y)j(y)
$$
so that:
$$
(\Delta-\epsilon M)\Phi = j
$$
in particular, you can take $j=M$.

Since you are assuming that $\epsilon$ is a small parameter, you can write $G$ as a perturbative series in $\epsilon$. This is the Born approximation if you truncate at leading order and interpret $M$ as a potential energy and $\Phi$ a first quantisation wave function.

Formally, using the unperturbed case:
$$
\begin{align}
G_0 &= \Delta^{-1} \\
&= -\frac{1}{4\pi |x-y|}
\end{align}
$$
you would write using linear algebra:
$$
\begin{align}
G &= \frac{1}{\Delta-\epsilon M} \\
 &= \frac{1}{\Delta}\frac{1}{1-\epsilon \Delta^{-1}M} \\
 &= \frac{1}{1-\epsilon \Delta^{-1}M}\frac{1}{\Delta} \\
&=  (1+\epsilon \Delta^{-1}M)\frac{1}{\Delta} \\
&= G_0 +\epsilon G_0 MG_0 \\
G(x,y) &= G_0(x,y)+\epsilon\int d^D z G_0(x,z)M(z)G_0(z,y) \\
&= -\frac{1}{4\pi |x-y|}+\frac{\epsilon}{(4\pi)^2}\int d^D z \frac{M(z)}{|x-z||y-z|}
\end{align}
$$
with the associate diagrammatic representation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This helps a lot. Many thanks. What if M did not break the translational invariance and we wouldn't like to take $\epsilon$ small? Do you think there could be a green function still?

Comment: If $M$ is translational invariant, then you get Helmholtz’ equation and you even have a closed form expression.

Comment: If you are not interested in the limit $\epsilon\to0$, then perturbative expansion isn’t valid and you’ll need to exploit other specificities to calculate the Green’s function (large $N$ expansion…)

Comment: In general, the mathematical existence of the Green’s function is not so much an issue. It is rather its computability.

Comment: Many many thanks. Last question. I would have Helmholtz with a different sign (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function ) it seems that is more like the Yukawa/Feynman Green's function with $k=\sqrt{\lambda M(r)}$
And yet this seems weird because M is not constant.

Comment: If it was, the Green's function would be
$$
G(r)=-\frac{e^{-\sqrt{\lambda M}r}}{4\pi r}
$$
Is it the same but with $M\to M(r)$?